# Calculate & move UIView on keyboard(show/hide)

Tags: swift, uiview, swift4

I am trying to calculate the position to move a UITextField along with its parent UIView if the keyboard is overlapping the field and move back to its original position after keyboard is closed.

I have already tried https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager and it does not work in my particular case.

To explain the problem, please refer two attached screenshot, one when keyboard is opened and another when it is closed.

[image: View Without Keyboard]
[image: View With Keyboard]

As you can see, on keyboard open, the text field is overlapping the keyboard, I want to move the text field along with popup view to readjust and sit above the keyboard.

Here is what I tried.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.startOriginY = self.frame.origin.y
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        let screenHeight = self.backgroundView.frame.height
        let viewHeight = self.frame.height
        let diffHeight = screenHeight - viewHeight - keyboardHeight
        if diffHeight < 0 {
            self.frame.origin.y = -self.textField.frame.height
        }
    }
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.frame.origin.y = self.startOriginY
}
```

This code moves the view to incorrect position. I am trying to figure out how to calculate the correct position to move the view and remove keyboard overlap.

What is the best way to go about solving this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you need to embedded your view inside a scroll view and use [Apple's example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) to handle the adjustment by altering the bottom content inset of the scroll view:

1. Embedded inside a scroll view
2. Register for keyboard notifications
3. Implement logic to handle the notifications by altering the bottom content inset

I have converted Apple's code snipe to Swift.

**Keyboard will show**:

```
if let info = notification.userInfo,
   let size = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject?) {
       let newSize = size.cgRectValue.size
       let contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, newSize.height, 0.0)
       scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
 }
```

**Keyboard will hide:**

```
let contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset
```

You can also add hard-coded offset to the `newSize.height` i.e: `newSize.height + 20`

Comment: Let me try this and get back. Thanks @OhadM

Comment: Of course, you need to check your scroll view is actually set and working well. Did you try to add to the newSize.height additional offset ? since you have prediction and a custom view above the keyboard